# What is the number format for this location in Israel?

Tags: where-on-earth, israel, maps, gps-navigation

These numbers represent the location of some place in Israel.

> 183409    264679

But I can't find them in Google Maps; they don't seem to convert to coordinates.

Does anyone have an idea? Maybe I should convert these numbers to some other format?

Comment: Where did you get those numbers from? Do you have an idea roughly which part of the world we're talking about?

Comment: Corrent. but I know for a fact that locations. maybe is wrong format or something?

Comment: Yes. it is Israel

Comment: Do you know the actual location more precisely? And/or do you have other sets of coordinates with the associated location? Where do the numbers come from?

Comment: Yes. It goes like that: Depth / Elevation /Location 1 / Location 2 ---> 71/924/183409/264679

Comment: It should be point about to 32.977923, 35.352499

Comment: I'll ask again: **Where did you get those numbers from?** The context you found them in could contain a lot of clues about which coordinate systems they might be expressed in.

Comment: You are right. I got it from my friend but he got no clue where it come from.

Comment: At [GIS.SE] they may have more knowledge of map coordinate systems, but I'm not sure they would welcome a question of this kind.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with travel.

Comment: Does not seem to be regular coordinates expressed differently (e.g in seconds). Does not look like MGRS, UTM, MapCode or Open Location Code. I'm puzzled by the other data...  Depth **and** Elevation? What is this data for? Are you sure the two locations are actual coordinates, not just an ID referencing another data set?

Comment: Voted to re-open as map references are for travel without doubt.

Comment: @Willeke I can see them as being potentially on-topic at [outdoors.se] but I see no travel content in this question. I mean, sure, one could tag "And can I travel there?" on the end but that's just [boat programming](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14470/what-is-the-boat-programming-meme-about). You can't just add "for programmers" to a question to make it about programming, and you can't just add "and can I travel there?" to a question to make it about travel.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By plugging your latitude/longitude coordiantes into https://zvikabenhaim.appspot.com/software/ITM/, we see that they correspond pretty closely to your mystery coordinates in the [Israel Cassini Soldner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israeli_Cassini_Soldner) system, also known as the "old Israel grid" (רשת ישראל ישנה).